# do-while loop wont end and crashes program

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Ive got a while loop that keeps running as long as an if is true at least once per loop but i cant find the reason why the loop wont stop. (there are a couple more ifs but i removed them because they are the exact same)

```
boolean changed = true;
    do{
        boolean stopLoop = false;

        if(remove1=="")
        {
            EquipmentSlot1.setText(EquipmentSlot2.getText());
            EquipmentSlot2.setText("");
            stopLoop = true;
        }
        if(remove2=="")
        {
            EquipmentSlot2.setText(EquipmentSlot3.getText());
            EquipmentSlot3.setText("");
            stopLoop = true;
        }
        if(remove3=="")
        {
            EquipmentSlot3.setText(EquipmentSlot4.getText());
            EquipmentSlot4.setText("");
            stopLoop = true;
        }
        if(stopLoop = false)
        {
            changed = false;
        }
    }while(changed);
```

Comment: [How do I compare strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (stopLoop = false)
```

to

```
if (stopLoop == false)
```

Note that `=` is for assignment, `==` for comparison.

Or better yet (and recommended):

```
if (!stop)
```

**Edit:**

Also, to [compare `String`s, use `equals()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java):

```
if (remove1.equals(""))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your last if is an assignment, not a test of equality, i.e. stopLoop = false should be == false

Second, changed has no way to be false in any if you have shown.